# How to aggregate over two columns with duplicates in both, and then some?

Tags: sql-server

This is probably very simple but I'm stupid and stuck and failed to find a thread that quite matched my problem...

I need to do an insert from a table, say `tblGameRecords`, that looks something like this:

```
tblGameRecords(ID:match_no, soccer_team_id, stadium, fake_injuries, hair_wax, date)
```

...into another table, `tblTeamRecords`, that needs to look like this:

```
tblTeamRecords(ID:soccer_team_id, stadium, fake_injuries, hair_wax, date)
```

Now, my problem is that in `tblGameRecords`:

*1. There are natural multiple occurrences of the same `soccer_team_id`'s.*

*2. There are natural multiple occurrences of the same `date`.*

*3. There are sometimes multiple occurrences of the same `soccer_team_id` on the same `date` (sigh...)*

I want to insert into `tblTeamRecord` one row per `soccer_team_id`. I want the *earliest* record of that team from `tblGameRecords`.

If the team makes its entrée in `tblGameRecords` as a duplicate, several times on the same `date`, I'm fine with *any one* row of those, because the other columns need to be filled with the respective values from that row, regardless of the actual values which may or may not differ from the other duplicates.

And I'm obviously having trouble formulating a query that lets me narrow down these multiples to just one. This is part of a stored procedure btw.

*** EDIT again: Deleted the redundant additional info ***

Comment: Can you post data sample?  This will help us to write the proper query.

Comment: I can't post a sample for various reasons unfortunately, but I will provide better info on the actual data types and values in a reply to myself below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to generate row numbers per date for each value of soccer_team_id (to partition the numbering by it) and then insert only those rows, where row number equals one:

```
;with cte as (
select soccer_team_id, stadium, fake_injuries, hair_wax, date, row_number() over(partition by soccer_team_id order by date) as row_no
from tblGameRecords
)
insert into tblTeamRecords(soccer_team_id, stadium, fake_injuries, hair_wax, date)
select soccer_team_id, stadium, fake_injuries, hair_wax, date
from cte
where row_no = 1
```

Comment: row_number() is a really nice trick to add to my rather small tool box. I had it set up similarly but was experimenting in vain with ROWS within the PARTITION parenthesis, which doesn't result in single value results and so doesn't work (you knew that). Unfortunately your solution doesn't work still. It only returns about a third of the 'soccer_team_id's' in 'tblGameRecords'. I'll post a reply to my question with more details about the actual data.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I checked the validity of the query on a single date against a select distinct from the source table, but must have been tired and made a mistake writing the condition. Yours IS the solution. Thank you Andrey Nikolov! Huge help for me.